# All permutations of array where each element in the array must be increasing by range between 0 and n

Tags: python, algorithm, math, rust, array-algorithms

Let's say I have a list of elements with values

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12]
```

Basically, the elements in the array may max have a difference of n, in this case three, in increasing order.

The array above would work like:

```
2-1 = 1 | difference of 1
3-2 = 1 | difference of 1
5-3 = 2 | difference of 2
6-5 = 1 | difference of 1
```

And so on.
How would I go about to find all permutations of an array with length x and a max difference of n?

Comment: So... what is valid permutation for given array?

Comment: I think if `x=4` and `n=2` then `[1,2,3,5]` would be a valid number...

Comment: Since you need to keep the order, this is very easy using recursion...

Comment: Wouldn't work with recursion, got a couple of hundred elements in the list. :/

Comment: Advent of Code 2020 Day 10...

Comment: Yupp, I have no idea how to do permutations.

Comment: Unless you're looking for a difference between absolute values of neighbor elements, there will either be only one solution or none at all.  Any array that is not in ascending order will have a negative difference between at least one element and the next one.  An array that is sorted will either meet your difference constraint or not. If you're actually looking fo differences in absolute value, please be specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for differences in absolute value, you can do this recursively by progressively adding each eligible element to the result:

here's an example using a recursive generator function:

```
def permuteSort(A,maxDiff,previous=None):
    if not A: yield []; return
    for i,a in enumerate(A):           
        if previous is not None and abs(a-previous) > maxDiff:               
            continue
        yield from ([a]+p for p in permuteSort(A[:i]+A[i+1:],maxDiff,a))
```

**Output**

```
for p in  permuteSort([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12],3):
    print(p,"differences:",[b-a for a,b in zip(p,p[1:])])
        
  
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12] differences: [1, 1, 2, 2, -1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 7, 9, 12] differences: [1, 1, 3, -1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [1, 3, -2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [2, -1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12] differences: [2, -1, 3, 2, -1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [-1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12] differences: [-1, 2, 2, 2, -1, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 9, 12] differences: [-1, 2, 3, -1, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [-2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 12] differences: [-2, 1, 3, 2, -1, 3, 3]
[5, 2, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12] differences: [-3, -1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
[6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 12] differences: [-3, -2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
[7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 6, 9, 12] differences: [-2, -3, -1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[12, 9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7] differences: [-3, -3, -3, -2, 1, 3, 2]
[12, 9, 6, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3] differences: [-3, -3, 1, -2, -3, -1, 2]
[12, 9, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3, 1] differences: [-3, -3, 1, -2, -3, 1, -2]
[12, 9, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1, 2] differences: [-3, -3, 1, -2, -2, -2, 1]
[12, 9, 6, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1] differences: [-3, -3, 1, -2, -2, -1, -1]
[12, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 6] differences: [-3, -2, -2, -3, -1, 2, 3]
[12, 9, 7, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2] differences: [-3, -2, -2, 1, -3, -2, 1]
[12, 9, 7, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1] differences: [-3, -2, -2, 1, -3, -1, -1]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 3, 1, 2, 5] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -3, -2, 1, 3]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 3, 5, 2, 1] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -3, 2, -3, -1]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 3] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -1, -3, -1, 2]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -1, -3, 1, -2]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -1, -2, -2, 1]
[12, 9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1] differences: [-3, -2, -1, -1, -2, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a recursion. Should print out all allowed values.
`x` is described as `required_number` and `n` is `diff`.

```
def getPermutations(cur_permutation, arr_to_check, required_number, diff):
    if len(arr_to_check) == 0:
        return

    if required_number == 0:
        print cur_permutation
        return

    cur_last_item = cur_permutation[-1]
    for index, arr_item in enumerate(arr_to_check):
        if arr_item - cur_last_item <= diff:
            new_copy = cur_permutation[:]
            new_copy.append(arr_item)
            return getPermutations(new_copy, arr_to_check[1:], required_number - 1, diff)
```

(This could also be done with keeping the require length and checking if `cur_permutation` is of that length).